# Не работает pyautogui. помогите

Tags: python, pycharm, импорт, pyautogui, модули

К слову у меня не работают еще и не которые другие модули. У меня питон 3.9.4

юзаю pycharm.когда пишу команду `pip install pyautogui` терминал пишет то что все нормально и ошибок нет. Но при всем этом PyCharm говорит что в коде ошибка и тыкает на строку `import pyautogui, sys`
[image: ошибка]

Я без понятия что делать. Программирую только неделю и очень много не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста.

Дополнение:
Прочитал что pyautogui работает только на версиях до 3.7.0 пожтому установил 3.6.0.
но все ровно не работает. К тому же появилась новая проблема
я куда то по натыкали теперь при попытке ввода `pip install pyautogui` вылезает это
`pip : Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и прави
льность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1

- pip install pyautogui
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`
  ```

Помогите решить теперь две проблемы)

Answer (score 0):

Следовало бы писать операционную систему, да и присылать сам фрагмент кода в таких вопросах. Войдите в терминал и проверьте наличие pip3 на вашем устройстве:

```
pip —version
```

Если у Вас не установлено, а по вашим словам очень похоже, ибо в противном случае у Вас не было бы проблем с этим: « Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета…»

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Если и это не поможет, попробуйте переустановить